# Period notation in group theory

Tags: notation, finite-fields

In the context of finite fields, quotient groups, and characteristics, what does
$$n.1=0$$
mean, i.e., what is the period notation?

Comment: it depends on the context it is written in, show more details !

Comment: I believe I just found it on Wikipedia, but in different notation. So might as well delete.

Comment: show us the link !

Comment: To make a wild guess it could be that this is an attempt to notationally differentiate between the multiplication within the field and the action of $\mathbb Z$ on the field ...?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_%28algebra%29 It is the third bullet in section 3. @HagenvonEitzen Differentiation indeed, as the author uses a multiplication dot elsewhere in the book.

Comment: @Christopher, which book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n \cdot 1$ most probably means $1 + 1 + \cdots + 1$, with $n$ terms.

Both $1$ and $+$ are to be interpreted in the given field.